# Acento Grave (`) en teclado español - MacBook

Tags: typescript, ascii, teclado

¿Cómo usar el símbolo llamado "Acento Grave" desde un teclado español?

He estado buscando y el código ASCII es el 96. Dejo enlace:

> http://www.elcodigoascii.com.ar/codigos-ascii/acento-grave-codigo-ascii-96.html

Éste símbolo es usado en algunos lenguajes de programación, por ejemplo, en Typescript, para los tempate strings.

Me gustaría saber si hay alguna combinación de teclas posibles, o incluso como marcar los códigos ASCII desde el macbook (Que no contiene el teclado numérico al lado)

Comment: El acento grave está a la derecha de la p. Mira: qwertyuiop`  ehh voilà. Tengo activado el teclado Español ISO.

Comment: Yo le puse etiquetas a mi teclado y el acento grave está a la izquierda de la z... no sé distribución uso, pero tiene una A. 8-)

Comment: Dios, como me lo he perdido? juraría que lo probé y no funcionaba, pero obviamente no lo hice correctamente, muchas gracias :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo puedes ver tú mismo yendo a `Preferencias - > Teclado -> Fuentes de entrada`:

- Si tienes activado **`Español`**:
  El acento grave estará en la **segunda tecla después de la p**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- Si tienes activado **`Español ISO`**:
  El acento grave estará en la **primera tecla después de la p**:
  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias, No entiendo como no llegué a probar esa tecla, juraría que la pobré y no funcionaba pero obviamente no lo hice hehe salu2 :)

Comment: Mi teclado es latin american y no sale el simbolo :(  [imagen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1fco.png)